# how to retrieve all the records from dataframe with a particular column having two values

Tags: r

I have a Data Frame called "specdata"

This is what the dataframe specdata consists:

```
head(specdata)

         Date sulfate nitrate ID
1: 2003-01-01             NA          NA     1
2: 2003-01-02             NA          NA     1
3: 2003-01-03             NA          NA     1
4: 2003-01-04             NA          NA     1
5: 2003-01-05             NA          NA     1
6: 2003-01-06             NA          NA     1

tail(specdata)

         Date sulfate nitrate  ID
1: 2004-12-26      NA      NA 332
2: 2004-12-27      NA      NA 332
3: 2004-12-28      NA      NA 332
4: 2004-12-29      NA      NA 332
5: 2004-12-30      NA      NA 332
6: 2004-12-31      NA      NA 332
```

The Data Frame contains ID column from 1 to 332 and sulfate has values other than NA's.

When I tried to retrieve all the values of sulfate column where ID column==1, It worked
I used the below code for that:

```
subset(specdata$sulfate,specdata$ID==1)
```

what I need is I should be able to retrieve all the values of sulfate where column id = 1:20, It didn't worked.

I used the below code for that:

```
subset(specdata$sulfate,specdata$ID==1) 

Warning message:
In specdata$ID == 1:20 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Read about `%in%` operator or `match` or even `which`.
Try this `specdata$sulfate[specdata$ID %in% 1:20]`

Comment: You may want to roll back that edit.  I had it looking nice. :)

Comment: @MrFlick: The coursera tag [got burninated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274845/1757964). Please don't use it any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just subsetting a single vector,

```
 specdata$sulfate[specdata$ID %in% 1:20]
```

should work just fine. `subset` is more useful for subsetting an entire data.frame like

```
 subset(specdata, ID %in% 1:20)
```

and I allows you to skip the explicit indexing ("$" or "[,]") though it does not work when you try to use variables for column names.